# how to give style to simple_form label?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to change the font-size and the spacing between the input box and label, in a form I've generated with the simple_form gem, 2.0.2. I'm sure there's a way to do this?

At present I have:

```
<%= f.input :comment, :input_html => { :wrap => :soft, :rows => 2}, :label => 'Type in box below:', :item_wrapper_class => 'type' %>
```

And in my css:

```
    .type{
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

I read in a post on this site that 'item_wrapper_class' would do the trick, but when I go to inspect element in Chrome, over the 'Type in box below:' part, it doesn't even pick up on the .type class, in my css - it just goes to the default label class, in bootstrap.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<%= f.input :comment, :input_html => { :wrap => :soft, :rows => 2}, :label => 'Type in box below:', :label_html => { :class => 'type' } %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this?

```
<%= f.input :comment, :input_html => { :wrap => :soft, :rows => 2}, :label => 'Type in box below:', wrapper_html: { class:  'type' } %>
```

Comment: As I result of your comment I tried: <%= f.input :comment, :input_html => { :wrap => :soft, :rows => 2}, :label => 'Type in box below:', :wrapper_html => { :class => 'type' } %>. So now, in Chrome debugging, I see the type class some ways down the list - it's listed after the 'bootstrap label' class. Then, when I uncheck the bootstrap label class, my type class applies. Any idea how I can make my class apply by default? Thanks for your help.